# How can a function ask its caller class to invoke one of its methods?

Tags: c++, function, class, member, design-decisions

I'm in a situation like this:

```
class Callee {
public:
  void request();
};

class Caller {
  void call() {
    Callee{}.request();
  }
  void invoke1(); // the implementation doesn't matter
  void invoke2(); // the implementation doesn't matter
  // more invoke()s
};
```

I want `Callee::request()` to request invocation of one of the `Caller::invoke()` member functions depending on the context which can be computed either in `Callee::request()` or in `Caller::call()`:

```
void Callee::request() {
  // do stuff
  switch (context) {
    // request one of the invoke()s to be run immediately
  }
  // do more stuff
}
```

Which solutions would be elegant? I don't want (from most to least important):

- `Callee` to know the definition of `Caller`;
- use templates;
- `Callee` to know the declaration of `Caller`;
- `Caller` to choose an `invoke()` on its own;

It's OK if `Callee::request()` receives some arguments from the `Caller`.

Comment: Pass the context to `request`

Comment: If all of the invoke functions have same signature, you can pass appropriate `std::function` object to the `Callee::request`.

Comment: You have conflicting requirements: if Callee isn't aware of Caller methods, how can it *choose* which one to call? Please clarify, do you want the calling for example to happen based on just index number or what? Or did I misunderstand the requirement for Callee to be able to choose?

Comment: There's no nice way to satisfy all your requirements. If you don't want to use templates, then you could use an abstract base-class for `Caller` that the `Callee` class needs to know about. Templates and passing the `Caller` objects to the `request` function seems like the simplest solution to me.

Comment: @Ashwani how? As I know, member functions require an object of the class to be called; doesn't it mean I can't just pass a `std::function`?

Comment: @hyde actually, I was hoping for a solution somehow connected with passing function pointers to the callee.

Comment: Ashwani is correct. You can store `[this](){this->invoke1();}` in a `std::function<void()>`. That's a lambda, if you don't recognize the form. It captures `this`.

Comment: @passing_through Of course, doing that is easy (passing `std::function` is easiest), if callee doesn't need to choose. But your requirement conflicts with this simple solution. You could edit the question to define what you mean by callee beimg able to choose the caller function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of ways you can achieve this.

- The most straightforward is to have `Callee::request()` return an
  `enum` value, which the `Caller` then does a `switch` on and invokes
  an appropriate function.  This means that caller and callee will have
  to both know this `enum`.
- Another way which is also in straightforward territory, though
  slightly more convoluted, is to pass a single function from the
  caller to the callee, which accepts that `enum` value as a parameter,
  so that by invoking this function the callee can indicate to the caller
  what it wants done.  Again the caller can `switch` on that value and
  invoke either `invoke1()` or `invoke2()` or what have you.
- Another way is to define an interface, (a class consisting of only
  pure virtual methods,) which contains `invoke1()` and `invoke2()`
  have the caller implement that interface, and pass that interface of
  itself to the callee, so that the callee can decide which function to
  call.  In this case, caller and callee will need to both have
  knowledge of this new interface.
- Another way is to pass the callee two pointers to functions, so that
  the callee can decide which one to call.  This way the callee does
  not need to know anything, but it does not scale very well, because
  what if you have 50 different functions?